# How to Tell if a Class implements an interface with a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following code:

```
public interface IInput
{

}

public interface IOutput
{

}

public interface IProvider<Input, Output>
{

}

public class Input : IInput
{

}

public class Output : IOutput
{

}

public class Provider: IProvider<Input, Output>
{

}
```

Now I would like to know if Provider Implements IProvider using reflection? 
I don't know how to do this.
I tried the following:

```
Provider test = new Provider();
var b = test.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IProvider<IInput, IOutput>));
```

It returns false..

I need help with this. I would like to avoid using Type Name (String) to figure this out.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

To test if it implements it *at all*:

```
var b = test.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
    x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IProvider<,>));
```

To find *of what*, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any`:

```
var b = test.GetType().GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
    x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IProvider<,>));
if(b != null)
{
    var ofWhat = b.GetGenericArguments(); // [Input, Output]
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the `IProvider` should be declared using interfaces not classes in its definition :

```
public interface IProvider<IInput, IOutput>
{

}
```

Then `Provider` class definition should be:

```
public class Provider: IProvider<IInput, IOutput>
{

}
```

And finally the call to `IsAssignableFrom` is backwards, it should be:

```
var b = typeof(IProvider<IInput, IOutput>).IsAssignableFrom(test.GetType());
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this using Mark's suggestion.

Here's the code:

```
(type.IsGenericType &&
                (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(IProvider<,>)).GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
```